# SharePoint Online Department Sync from On-Prem AD

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, user-profile-service

My SharePoint Online User Profile Application is being synced from On-Prem AD. The User Profile in SharePoint Online contains values for the Department that are not being supplied by our On-Prem AD. I am not sure where all this is coming from.

Also, we are getting a lot of deprecated users synced in our SharePoint Online, especially people who have left the organization. How do I troubleshoot this? I know that the AD Connect sync properties are not configurable which includes Department property.

Comment: Do you have Azure AD in between or is it direct sync?

Comment: Yes, have an Azure AD and I checked to see that those values are not in Azure AD. So it seems that the sync is working as designed, but somewhere in between from Azure to UPA, the values are getting populated. Manual entry can be a possibility from Delve, may be?